# why the attribute contentEditable of input text box does not work in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, input, textbox, contenteditable

In my .net project ,these are so many codes like this

```
< asp:TextBox ID="txtDeparment" runat="server" contentEditable="false">< /asp:TextBox>
```

it works well In IE,but in Chrome, it doesn't work. but you cann't simply replace it by ReadOnly.

How can I  resolve this problem in minimum  changes?

Comment: is there a particular reason that you're using a server-side text box instead of just `<input type='text'>`?

Answer (score -1):

In order to make a text box un-editable you should use the following CSS attributes:

```
user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
```

These CSS attributes don't allow selecting the element, which in the case of an input field, also denies editing it.

Comment: As you're already stating, that CSS will prevent the user from *selecting* the content of the input, but the question is about how to prevent *editing* in Chrome.